# How can i destroy the surrounding of a collision?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a protective wall of stacked rectangles that the player is behind. If the protective wall collides with a bomb, I not only want to destroy the one rectangle but also the side and bottom neighbors. Does anyone have an idea how to get the coordinates of the neighbors?
i create the wall with this code:

```
for j in range(int(bodenebenen)):             
    for i in range(int(bodenspalten)):
                m = Boden(int(i)*bodenbreite,(int(j)*bodenhoehe) ,int(bodenbreite),int(bodenhoehe),620,schutzcolor[random.randint(0,len(schutzcolor) - 1)])          
                protectivewall.add(m)
                alle_sprites.add(m)

 hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bombs,protectivewall,True,True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to [inflate](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) the rectangles of the bombs before collision detection. A larger rectangle, hits more objects. Use [`inflate_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate_ip) to inflate the rectangles in place and shrink (inverse inflate) the remaining bombs after collision detection. You just need to find a good size by which you want to enlarge the rectangles. I use 10 here just as an example:

```py
for b in bombs:
    b.rect.inflate_ip(10, 10)
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bombs, protectivewall, True, True)
for b in bombs:
    b.rect.inflate_ip(-10, -10)
```

Comment: @Rabbit: The basic idea is good and it works. if I choose the factor 10 there is no clear effect. This occurs from a factor of 100. However, the bomb then destroys parts of the wall, although it is still clearly above the wall.

Comment: Alternatively, can I not connect the rectangles of the wall with indices x,y. if then, for example, the rectangle [1,5] is hit, do I destroy it with kill??? the rectangles [1,4],[1,5],[1,6]. and Rectangle[2,5]. how would I address and index these?

Comment: The destruction in width can take place via a high x value. I forgot to say that.